# npm test fails in Jenkins but passes in local

Tags: node.js, reactjs, unit-testing, npm, jenkins-pipeline

npm test Fails

Getting following error

```
FAIL src/Tests/Workflow.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/tmp/jest_4df/jest-transform-cache-4e6d562894209be60da269aa86f9333c-d1d5bfaad8659acd06069518d3e76e6c/48'

      at createDirectory (node_modules/jest-util/build/createDirectory.js:68:10)
      at ScriptTransformer._getFileCachePath (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:306:37)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:429:32)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:569:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:607:25)

FAIL src/Tests/app.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/tmp/jest_4df/jest-transform-cache-4e6d562894209be60da269aa86f9333c-d1d5bfaad8659acd06069518d3e76e6c/48'

      at createDirectory (node_modules/jest-util/build/createDirectory.js:68:10)
      at ScriptTransformer._getFileCachePath (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:306:37)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:429:32)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:569:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:607:25)

FAIL src/Tests/AuthenticationForm.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/tmp/jest_4df/jest-transform-cache-4e6d562894209be60da269aa86f9333c-d1d5bfaad8659acd06069518d3e76e6c/48'

      at createDirectory (node_modules/jest-util/build/createDirectory.js:68:10)
      at ScriptTransformer._getFileCachePath (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:306:37)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:429:32)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:569:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:607:25)

FAIL src/Tests/Authentication.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/tmp/jest_4df/jest-transform-cache-4e6d562894209be60da269aa86f9333c-d1d5bfaad8659acd06069518d3e76e6c/48'

      at createDirectory (node_modules/jest-util/build/createDirectory.js:68:10)
      at ScriptTransformer._getFileCachePath (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:306:37)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:429:32)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:569:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:607:25)

FAIL src/Tests/AuthenticationFormInputField.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/tmp/jest_4df/jest-transform-cache-4e6d562894209be60da269aa86f9333c-d1d5bfaad8659acd06069518d3e76e6c/48'

      at createDirectory (node_modules/jest-util/build/createDirectory.js:68:10)
      at ScriptTransformer._getFileCachePath (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:306:37)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:429:32)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:569:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:607:25)

FAIL src/Tests/UserInputForm.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/tmp/jest_4df/jest-transform-cache-4e6d562894209be60da269aa86f9333c-d1d5bfaad8659acd06069518d3e76e6c/48'

      at createDirectory (node_modules/jest-util/build/createDirectory.js:68:10)
      at ScriptTransformer._getFileCachePath (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:306:37)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:429:32)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:569:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:607:25)

FAIL src/Tests/UserInputFormField.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir '/tmp/jest_4df/jest-transform-cache-4e6d562894209be60da269aa86f9333c-d1d5bfaad8659acd06069518d3e76e6c/48'

      at createDirectory (node_modules/jest-util/build/createDirectory.js:68:10)
      at ScriptTransformer._getFileCachePath (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:306:37)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:429:32)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:569:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:607:25)

Test Suites: 7 failed, 7 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.251 s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

The above issue seems to be like an issue in cache. I tried solving it using different solution given on stack overflow for something similar but nothing helped.

I have tried to resolve it using following -

- Deleting node module folder and package-lock json
- npm cache clean --force
- npm cache verify
- npm install

In my package.json I have this

```
{
  "name": "123,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.9",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.5",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^1.0.6",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-csv": "^2.0.3",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-loader-spinner": "^4.0.0",
    "react-promise-tracker": "^2.1.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^4.1.0",
    "react-select-event": "^5.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test:coverage": "react-scripts test --coverage",
    "test:update": "react-scripts test --updateSnapshot"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

Comment: looks like it might be your node version: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/10347

Comment: Thanks! Yes I too think so it is an issue due to node version. Will update the node version in my Jenkins and check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue.

Jenkins was using version 10.8.0 and in my project Jest version was 26.
Jest 26 doesn't support node <10.14.2.

You will have to downgrade the version of your jest or u will have to change your node version.

Comment: This resolved it for me as well. I was simply on the wrong (old) version of node.